# How to determine groups of consecutive values?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some data in column A like this

```
ColA
Z
A

Z
A

Z
A
A
B
B
B

Z
B
B

Z
C
C
C
D
D
```

**I want to print in column B**

- "0" if cell in A = "Z"
- empty when cell in A is empty
- When a group begins for example with letter A, then all next A's should be marked with 1.
- When a next group begins, i.e. with letter B, then mark all following B's with 2,
- When begins a new group i.e with letter C, mark with value 1 again and so on.
- the values in column A are not letters in alphabetical sequence. Is only an example. I only know the value of "Z", the groups could have any string

This is, alternate assigning values 1 and 2 for each new group. I hope make sense.

This is my current code

```vb
Sub t1()
Dim dict As Object

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 1 To 24
    If Cells(i, "A") = "Z" Then
        Cells(i, "B") = "0"
    ElseIf Cells(i, "A") <> "Z" And Cells(i, "A") <> "" Then
        counter = counter + 1
        dict.Add Key:=Cells(i, "A"), Item:=1
        
        If Not dict.Exists(Cells(i, "A")) Then
            If counter Mod 2 = 1 Then
                Cells(i, "B") = "1"
            Else
                Cells(i, "B") = "2"
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

My curent output in column B and my expected output in Column Cells

```
ColA ColB    ColC
Z      0     0
A      1     1
           
Z      0     0
A      2     1
           
Z      0     0
A      1     1
A      2     1
B      1     2
B      2     2
B      1     2
           
Z      0     0
B      2     2
B      1     2
           
Z      0     0
C      2     1
C      1     1
C      2     1
D      1     2
D      2     2
```

Maybe someone could help me. Thanks

Comment: Why is the value of B after Z1 2?

Comment: Actually all values are "Z", the Z1 was a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: Quick question. Why is the value of "B", 2 in row 14 and 15? Should it not be "1". Is it a typo? If not, then d you mean that if the letters get repeated then it should retain it's original value? If yes then I will have to amend the formula that I gave you below...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hello, no. Imagine Z and empty values don't exist. Then we have this input A,A,A,B,C,C,C,C,D,D,A,E,E,E,B,A. I only want the alternation between 1 and 2 for each new group. Doesn't matter if A has appeared before, should be taken as new group. With this input the, output should be 1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2 – Ger Cas 9 hours ago

Try this crazy formula (I am sure this can be made simpler). Put this in cell `B2` as shown in the screenshot below

`=IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",IF(A2="Z",0,IF(A2=A1,B1,IF(OR(A1="Z",ISBLANK(A1)),IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A1,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($1:1)/($A$1:$A1=A2),1))),IFERROR((A1+1),1),IF(OR(INDEX($A$1:$A1,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($1:1)/($A$1:$A1=A2),1)+1)="Z",INDEX($A$1:$A1,AGGREGATE(14,6,ROW($1:1)/($A$1:$A1=A2),1)+1)=""),INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A2,$A$1:$A1,0),1),1)),IF(B1=1,2,IF(B1=2,1,""))))))`

Let's say you data looks like this

[image]

**Explanation**

Following a sequence of checks in the below order

1. **ISBLANK(A2)**: Check if the cell is empty. If it is empty then keep output blank.
2. **A2="Z"**: Check if the cell has "Z". Output `0`.
3. **A2<>A1**: Check if the value changes in column A. If it doesn't then pick up value from top. If it changes then see next check
4. Then we use `INDEX` with `AGGREGATE()` to do a reverse match to find the occurence of the value and if a match is found then pull the respective value from Column `B`

Comment: Great solution and this can be easily used in VBA too. By the way, the results in row 15 and 16 should be 2 according to the logic of the OP.

Comment: I assumed that it is a typo. If not then it can be easily fixed. Posted a query under the question :)

Comment: Edited original post trying to explain better the logic. Thanks

Comment: @GerCas: Ok quick question. If you had `Z,C,C,A,D,D` instead of `Z,C,C,C,D,D` in the above scenario then what would `0,1,1,1,2,2` change to? The reason why I ask is because `C` becomes `1` as per your logic but `A` already has a value of `1` from above so the output in my opinion should be `0 (For Z),
1(For C),
1(For C),
1(For A),
2(For D),
2(For D),` If this is correct, then I have the formula ready for you

Comment: Hello, if A already appeared and has value 1, but appears again below as in your example, should be taken as a new group. The alternation between 1 and 2 happens when there is a change of groups. I hope make sense

Comment: So, even when A had value 1 before, if appears again after the C's should be for Z,C,C,A,D,D = 0,1,1,2,1,1

Comment: @GerCas: Why is D one? should it not be 3?  0,1,1,2,3,3 for `Z,C,C,A,D,D`

Comment: Hello, no. Imagine Z and empty values don't exist. Then we have this input A,A,A,B,C,C,C,C,D,D,A,E,E,E,B,A. I only want the alternation between 1 and 2 for each new group. Doesn't matter if A has appeared before, should be taken as new group. With this input the, output should be 1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,2,2,2,1,2

Comment: @GerCas: Check the post now. Does it work as per your specifications? :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout Excellent. Is an anaconda formula hehe, but it seems to work and print correct output. I think this was a headache for you. Thanks dor take of your time to help.

Comment: @GerCas: No it was not a heahache. I was simply not able to give it time. lot of work on professional front. I am sure the formula can be optimized...

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
    Dim r As Range, c As Range, s As String, n As Long, x As Long, y As Long
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Columns(2).ClearContents
        For Each r In .Columns(1).SpecialCells(2).Areas
            n = 0: x = 0
            For Each c In r
                If c.Value = "Z" Then
                    c.Offset(, 1).Value = 0
                Else
                    If c.Value <> s And c.Address = r(2).Address Then y = 0
                    If c.Value <> c.Offset(-1).Value And c.Address = r(2).Address And s <> "" Then
                        If c.Value = s Then c.Offset(, 1).Value = y: GoTo Skipper
                    End If
                    If c.Value <> c.Offset(-1).Value Then
                        n = n + 1: c.Offset(, 1).Value = n + y
                    Else
                        c.Offset(, 1).Value = c.Offset(-1, 1).Value
                    End If
                End If
Skipper:
                x = x + 1
                If r.Cells.Count = x Then s = c.Value: y = c.Offset(, 1).Value
            Next c
        Next r
    End With
End Sub
```

Here's snapshot
[image]

Comment: The code ran well on my side. Can you debug.print the addresses of c and r(2)?

Comment: Use F8 to follow the lines of the code and at the line of error, type in the immediate window `?c.address` and `?r(2).address` to see what's wrong.

Comment: Maybe other members test the code and tell us if the code works or not. That's weird.

Comment: I don't know what's wrong exactly with you. I suppose sheet name is "Sheet1" and the data starts at A1 ..If the problem is still there, upload the workbook you are working on to have a look.

Comment: Hi, I tested in another machine and it works. Thank you. The only issue is that if you continue adding more letters in column A, the output doesn´t alternate between 1 and 2, but continues incrementing to 3, 4, 5, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim vDB, vR()
    Dim Dict As Object
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim cnt As Integer
    
    vDB = Range("a1", Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    
    ReDim vR(1 To r, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To r
        If vDB(i, 1) = "" Then
            cnt = 0
            Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") '
        Else
            If vDB(i, 1) Like "Z*" Then
                vR(i, 1) = 0
            Else
                If Dict.Exists(vDB(i, 1)) Then
                    vR(i, 1) = Dict(vDB(i, 1))
                Else
                    cnt = cnt + 1
                    Dict.Add vDB(i, 1), cnt
                    vR(i, 1) = Dict(vDB(i, 1))
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Range("b1").Resize(r) = vR
End Sub
```

### Result image

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Your output is correct from row 1 to row 14 and from row 17 to 23. Row 15:16 should have value 2.

Comment: @GerCas as for the row 19 to 21 which has the value C, it is supposed as for your logic to be 3 not 1 as in the output you posted!! And D in row 22 and 23 to be 4

Comment: @YasserKhalil in the output I show in my post the values for groups of consecutive letters change between 1 and 2, not from 1, 2, 3,4.... For Z would be 0, for groups alternate between 1 and 2. I hope make sense