# query using group by in Python and Excel

Tags: python, excel

Hey just wondering if I was provided the following table

```
   col_a  col_b
0  A      1
1  B      2
2  B      3
3  C      4
4  D      5
5  D      6
6  E      3
7  A      2
8  A      1
```

how I can get the following result using Python and Excel? Much appreciated

```
   col_a  min  max
0  A      1    1
1  B      2    3
2  C      4    4
3  D      5    6
4  E      3    3
5  A      1    2
```

Comment: You need something similar to the following answer. You just need to change aggregation to min and max I think. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41621009/11560290.

Comment: Using what tools?  Do you want to "control" Excel, or are you thinking you'll read an xlsx file and produce a different xlsx file?

Answer (score 1):

## Python

### Using `itertools.groupby()` method

The `ìtertools.groupby()` function returns consecutive keys and groups from the iterable. 
You can read more about how to use `itertools.groupby()` on the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) or on [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773/how-do-i-use-itertools-groupby).

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_a': ['A','B','B','C','D','D','E','A','A'],
    'col_b': [1,2,3,4,5,6,3,2,1]
})

groups = []
for key, group in itertools.groupby(df.index, lambda x: df['col_a'][x]):
    col_b_values = df.loc[group, 'col_b'].tolist() # Extract the 'col_b' values as a list
    groups.append({
        'col_a': key,
        'min': min(col_b_values),
        'max': max(col_b_values)
    })

pd.DataFrame(groups)
```

Output:

```
    col_a   min max
0   A   1   1
1   B   2   3
2   C   4   4
3   D   5   6
4   E   3   3
5   A   1   2
```

#### Using Pandas `shift().cumsum()` and `groupby` methods

You can create a new column which identifies consecutive rows in `col_a` using `shift().cumsum()`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_a': ['A','B','B','C','D','D','E','A','A'],
    'col_b': [1,2,3,4,5,6,3,2,1]
})

df['group'] = (df.col_a != df.col_a.shift()).cumsum()
```

The output will look like:

```
  col_a col_b group
0   A   1   1
1   B   2   2
2   B   3   2
3   C   4   3
4   D   5   4
5   D   6   4
6   E   3   5
7   A   2   6
8   A   1   6
```

And then group by the df['group'] column:

```
df.groupby(['group','col_a'], as_index=True).agg(min=('col_b','min'), max=('col_b', 'max')).reset_index(level='group',drop=True).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
 col_a  min max
0   A   1   1
1   B   2   3
2   C   4   4
3   D   5   6
4   E   3   3
5   A   1   2
```

---

## Excel

### Using `LAMBDA` and `OFFSET` functions

With Microsoft's [introduction of dynamic arrays](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-vs-legacy-cse-array-formulas-ca421f1b-fbb2-4c99-9924-df571bd4f1b4) in the recent years, we can implement approximately same logic in Excel without the use of VBA.

First we will create an array which for each row of col_a identifies whether it is a duplicate consecutive. Then we create a range that generates a unique consecutive group ID and then add min/max arrays  to get minimum and maximum col_b values for each consecutive group ID. Finally we group it by group ID and drop duplicates.
The function is:

```
=LET(
col_a,$A$2:$A$10,
col_b,$B$2:$B$10,
is_dup,MAP(col_a,OFFSET(col_a,-1,0),LAMBDA(a_1,a_2,a_1=a_2)),
groupids,SCAN(0,is_dup,LAMBDA(a,r,IF(r,0+a,a+1))),
_min_val,BYROW(groupids,LAMBDA(r,TAKE(SORT(FILTER(col_b,groupids=r),,1),1))),
_max_val,BYROW(groupids,LAMBDA(r,TAKE(SORT(FILTER(col_b,groupids=r),,-1),1))),
VSTACK({"col_a","min","max"},CHOOSECOLS(UNIQUE(HSTACK(col_a,groupids,_min_val,_max_val)),1,3,4))
)
```

[Excel implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNTN3.jpg)

### Other methods using Excel

You might be able to achieve similar result using the `Scripting.Dictionary` object in VBA or combination of `INDEX` and `AGGREGATE` functions (see [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63083653/how-to-determine-groups-of-consecutive-values))

Answer (score 0):

```
df['cs'] = (df['col_a'] != df['col_a'].shift()).cumsum()
aaa = (df.groupby(['cs', 'col_a'])['col_b'].aggregate(['min', 'max'])).reset_index().drop(columns=['cs'])

print(aaa)
```

Output

```
  col_a  min  max
0     A    1    1
1     B    2    3
2     C    4    4
3     D    5    6
4     E    3    3
5     A    1    2
```

Here, in the created column `'cs'`, the current line and the next row are checked for inequality. Where the condition is true, it is set to `True`, then the `cumulative` sum is calculated and this column is used for `grouping`. The aggregates are calculated, the indexes are reset and the 'cs' column is removed.